# ADO.NET example that has no logic, dataGrid fill from uknown data

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagrid, ado.net

Ok guys, here is the code that have logic and it's simple, but result that brings to datagrid has no logic at all.

Here is SQl query for making table and fill table

```
 Create Table Students
(
    ID int primary key identity,
    FirstName nvarchar(50),
    LastName nvarchar(50),
    Gender nvarchar(50)
)
GO


Insert into Students values ('Mark', 'Hastings', 'Male')
Insert into Students values ('Steve', 'Pound', 'Male')
Insert into Students values ('Ben', 'Hoskins', 'Male')
Insert into Students values ('Philip', 'Hastings', 'Male')
Insert into Students values ('Mary', 'Lambeth', 'Female')
GO
```

---

Here is code behind, it very simple as u see

```
string  cs=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SampleConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("select * from Students", con);

     con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
      {
    GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

con.Close();
```

and ASPX

```
<div>
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
</div>
```

---

the result in Datagrid is ;

```
StudentID   StudentName
2           John
```

if u see, there is no John in the table and I just can't figure it out what it's going.....

This is made in VS2013 , framework 4.5 and MsSQL 2014

thx

Comment: Are you connecting to proper database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the CREATE TABLE Students, insert :

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXIST Students
```

Comment: There is just one table, you one to say that i have two tables with same name or what?

Comment: If you retrieve "john" in the dataTable, I assumed that your Student table is already built with "John" in it and that the CREATE command fails providing an error that you didn't manage.

Comment: well, there is a problem, nobody reads topic or question, this script only, nothing less or nothing more. I just drop table and create again with this script, and my connection string is tested.